# JQuery .animate() doesn't animate. Instead, it waits duration and immediately makes the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

This is the most frustrating thing ever. Instead of animating smoothly like it's supposed to, for some reason, it waits for the full duration of the animation (1000ms) and then immediately sets the height of my `.nowGone` div. I'm using IE 11.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nowGone">
        <!-- large table with lots of rows -->
    </div>
    <div class="more">
        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Show</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Here's my CSS:**

```
.more {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.nowGone {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Here's my JQuery:**

```
$(function () {

    $(".nowGone").css('display', 'block');
    var goneheight = $(".nowGone").css('height');
    $(".nowGone").css('height', '0px');

    $(".more").find("a").mousedown(function() {
        $(".nowGone").animate({ height : goneheight }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Try to see if it behaves the same in Chrome/Firefox/Opera. I've tried to write JScript on the window script host with timeouts and it has the _exact_ same problem: instead of taking delays in sequence, it seems to hoist them up at the top or to arbitrary points. I think this is a IE11 problem, not somthing in your code.

Comment: Historically, IE required wrapping the `div` in a containment `div` and doing the animation on the container.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/K8f28/